# Reading in Strings from a File

Tags: java, string, file

Is it possible to read in Strings from a file one at a time like you can with integers using the .nextint() function? Or would you have to go about reading in all of the strings into one array and then split that one big array by whitespaces to get each individual string. So for example, if I had a file with..

```
Apple bottom jeans boots with the fur.
```

Is there a way to read in Apple, then bottom, then jeans, and so on? Or do you have to read all the strings in at once. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Use [`Scanner#next`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next())...

Comment: You're already using Scanner.nextInt(). Read the documentation for Scanner().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Scanner#next`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29). Example:

```
String foo = "Apple bottom jeans boots with the fur";
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(foo);
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(scanner.next());
}
```

Prints:

```
Apple
bottom
jeans
boots
with
the
fur
```

For your case, initialize the `Scanner` with a `File` pointing to the desired file.